# Flutter change single value in class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am still learning and trying to get used to classes etc... I am not sure if this is possible but I have a class that I pass to the screen. Then on that screen I work with the data from one field, then I want to pass the same value onto the next page with everything the same, except what I worked on.

For example, using the below class, I could have page1 that I pass the Sample too... then on page one I read List1 and edit the list to be something else... I then want to pass the Sample to page2 but with the list now having the data that I had worked on not the original data.

```
class Sample {
  final String field1;
  final String field2;
  final String field3;
  final String field4;
  final List List1;
  Sample({ this.field1, this.field2, this.field3, this.field4, this.List1 });
}
```

I am currently getting around it by passing each field that hasn't been changed through widget.Sample.field1, etc... but if I add a new field I need to remember to set it on all pages. It would be great if I could do something like widget.Sample.replace(List1, NewList).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the `copyWith` pattern. You can create a copy of the structure and only modify what you want to change. It's pretty straightforward to write by hand but there are also packages that can help generate this code for you.

```dart
class Sample {
  final String? field1;
  final String? field2;
  final String? field3;
  final String? field4;
  final List? list1;

  Sample({
    this.field1,
    this.field2,
    this.field3,
    this.field4,
    this.list1,
  });

  Sample copyWith({
    String? field1,
    String? field2,
    String? field3,
    String? field4,
    List? list1,
  }) =>
      Sample(
        field1: field1 ?? this.field1,
        field2: field2 ?? this.field2,
        field3: field3 ?? this.field3,
        field4: field4 ?? this.field4,
        list1: list1 ?? this.list1,
      );
}

void main() {
  var sample = Sample(
    field1: 'foo',
    field2: 'bar',
    list1: ['cat', 'dog'],
  );

  print(sample.field1); // 'foo'
  print(sample.field2); // 'bar'
  print(sample.list1); // ['cat', 'dog']

  sample = sample.copyWith(
    field3: 'batz',
    list1: [...?sample.list1, 'armadillo'],
  );

  print(sample.field1); // 'foo'
  print(sample.field2); // 'bar'
  print(sample.field3); // 'batz'
  print(sample.list1); // ['cat', 'dog', 'armadillo']
}
```

Keep in mind that this implementation is simple and won't set null values.

Code generators:

- [functional_data](https://pub.dev/packages/functional_data)
- [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed)

Comment: Thanks for this... how would I then call the old Sample but change only 1 value?

Comment: Calling `copyWith()` on the "old" instance creates a new instance with the changes. I've update the answer with example usage.

If you're asking more about state management, this might not be the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Crucial part of this example is assigning instance to new variable `anotherSample`

Comment: Updated the example to remove `anotherSample` and just reassign `sample`.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the link [Dart/Flutter – Convert/Parse JSON string, array into Object, List](https://bezkoder.com/dart-flutter-parse-json-string-array-to-object-list/).

Answer (score 0):

You can update your instance variable (`List List1`) by removing final keyword. Dart support implicit getters and setters. So by using setter we can update the list without creating new object and copying all other/updated properties to it.

To update list

```
setState(() {
   model.List1=["X","Y","Z"];
});
```